# How do I make a search insensitive in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, search, case-insensitive

This is my first post, please let me know how to improve.

My question is kind of in 2 parts. First, I'm making a search function that takes text in a text box, references it in a database and adds the result to a data grid view. It works, but it is case sensitive, and long winded. I've managed to get around the sensitivity issue, but not without adding a ton of lines. Also, my method is producing multiple of the same result in the data grid view.

My questions are: is there an easier way to code this search, and how can I make it insensitive?

```
 dgvFileInfo.Rows.Clear()

    If searchBox.Text = "" Then 

    ElseIf srchCrit = "ProjectNumber" Then
        Dim srchDesc As String = ""
        Dim rtrnDesc As String = ""
        Dim j As Integer = 0

        For Each row As DataRow In TblFiles.Rows
            rtrnDesc = row.Item(srchCrit).ToString
            srchDesc = searchBox.Text
            If rtrnDesc.Contains(srchDesc) Then
                dgvFileInfo.Rows.Add()
                dgvFileInfo.Item(0, j).Value = row.Item("ProjectNumber").ToString
                dgvFileInfo.Item(1, j).Value = row.Item("ProjectName").ToString
                dgvFileInfo.Item(2, j).Value = row.Item("Client").ToString
                dgvFileInfo.Item(3, j).Value = row.Item("City").ToString & ", " & row.Item("State").ToString
                j += 1
            End If
        Next
    Else
        Dim srchDesc As String = ""
        Dim rtrnDesc As String = ""
        Dim j As Integer = 0

        Dim letter As Char = searchBox.Text.Substring(0, 1)
        Dim line As String = searchBox.Text.Substring(1, searchBox.Text.Length - 1)

        For Each row As DataRow In TblFiles.Rows '***Here's my sensitivity issue**
            rtrnDesc = row.Item(srchCrit).ToString
            srchDesc = UCase(letter) & line
            If rtrnDesc.Contains(srchDesc) Then
                dgvFileInfo.Rows.Add()
                dgvFileInfo.Item(0, j).Value = row.Item("ProjectNumber").ToString
                dgvFileInfo.Item(1, j).Value = row.Item("ProjectName").ToString
                dgvFileInfo.Item(2, j).Value = row.Item("Client").ToString
                dgvFileInfo.Item(3, j).Value = row.Item("City").ToString & ", " & row.Item("State").ToString
                j += 1
            End If

            srchDesc = LCase(letter) & line
            If rtrnDesc.Contains(srchDesc) Then
                dgvFileInfo.Rows.Add()
                dgvFileInfo.Item(0, j).Value = row.Item("ProjectNumber").ToString
                dgvFileInfo.Item(1, j).Value = row.Item("ProjectName").ToString
                dgvFileInfo.Item(2, j).Value = row.Item("Client").ToString
                dgvFileInfo.Item(3, j).Value = row.Item("City").ToString & ", " & row.Item("State").ToString
                j += 1
            End If

            srchDesc = LCase(letter) & LCase(line)
            If rtrnDesc.Contains(srchDesc) Then
                dgvFileInfo.Rows.Add()
                dgvFileInfo.Item(0, j).Value = row.Item("ProjectNumber").ToString
                dgvFileInfo.Item(1, j).Value = row.Item("ProjectName").ToString
                dgvFileInfo.Item(2, j).Value = row.Item("Client").ToString
                dgvFileInfo.Item(3, j).Value = row.Item("City").ToString & ", " & row.Item("State").ToString
                j += 1
            End If

            srchDesc = UCase(letter) & UCase(line)
            If rtrnDesc.Contains(srchDesc) Then
                dgvFileInfo.Rows.Add()
                dgvFileInfo.Item(0, j).Value = row.Item("ProjectNumber").ToString
                dgvFileInfo.Item(1, j).Value = row.Item("ProjectName").ToString
                dgvFileInfo.Item(2, j).Value = row.Item("Client").ToString
                dgvFileInfo.Item(3, j).Value = row.Item("City").ToString & ", " & row.Item("State").ToString
                j += 1
            End If

        Next

    End If
```

Comment: One way to improve - don't post so much irrelevant code. Another is to always include the [tag:vb.net] tag when posting a VB.NET question. That way, the VB.NET experts will see your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nice method for searching with case insensitivity via some other posts.

```
If myString.IndexOf(myVar, 0, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1 Then
       'your code here
End If
```

This has been working very well for me, I hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

1) You are doing comparisons on the application side, meaning it is happening in the VB code.  To do a case insensitive search, you can either do a `.ToUpper()` or `.ToLower()` and compare that way.  Or, you can use `String.Compare`.

```
' using ToUpper (ToLower would be the same)
Dim isFound as Boolean = ("My string".ToUpper() = row("myField").ToString().ToUpper())

' using String.Compare
Dim isFound as Boolean = (String.Compare("My String", row("myField"), True) = 0)
```

2) The easiest way to do this would be to do the searching in the database.  If you can do that and your database is case insensitive (SQL Server instances default to case insensitive), you can now use LINQ and/or an ORM like NHibernate to build and execute sql in the database.  That is going to be a long series of questions that have been answered numerous times here on SO and around the web.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give those suggestions a try.